How can I install extras from a git subdirectory with pip?
pip supports VCS installs, as documented in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/ (related question: How can I install from a git subdirectory with pip?).
However, it seems that it's not possible to install providing the extras, i.e. the optional dependencies (as in https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#optional-dependencies). Is this right? Is there any workaround?

Do you mean something like pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git[extra]?

Yes, but if I do this I get an error is not a valid repository name. I think it gets parsed as part of the repository name.

It seems the command must be pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git#[extra] — note #. Also could be pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra]. For example pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git[mysql,postgres]" doesn't work but pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git#[mysql,postgres]" and pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git#egg=sqlobject[mysql,postgres]" work. Is it what you want?

Yes, it works! I adapted it to pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git#[extra]#subdirectory=path/to/subdir. Would you like to write down a proper answer, or should I do it? And can I ask you the source, since I didn't find any?

As stated in https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11617 (tl;dr got to https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/11617#issuecomment-1324285376), the right way to do it is
pip install "package_name[extras] @ git+https://github.com/user/project.git#subdirectory=path/to/subdir".
Thanks to @phd: it's answer works for the time being, but as it emerges from the referred issue discussion this is deprecated and will possibly be made into an error in next releases. The deprecation warning reads:
DEPRECATION: git+ssh://****@github.com/... contains an egg fragment with a non-PEP 508 name pip 25.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to use the req @ url syntax, and remove the egg fragment. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11617.

Extras must be separated from repository URL:
pip install "git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra]"

With a subdirectory:
pip install "git+https://github.com/user/project.git#subdirectory=/path"

or fully:
pip install "git+https://github.com/user/project.git#egg=project[extra]&subdirectory=/path"


As I wrote in a previous comment, for me the subdirectory command that works is pip install git+https://github.com/user/project.git#[extra]#subdirectory=path/to/subdir, rather than the ones you suggested.

@Gabriele Perhaps pip understands more divergent syntax but the documented one is that: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/vcs-support/#url-fragments

The extras part is not documented though; that page was my starting point. It's also explicitly stated that «The egg fragment should be a bare project name», while in your examples it is not. Specifically, the first example command raises a PEP warning; the second and third ones fail, supposedly because they try to include the [extra] in the subdirectory path. I tried that on a private project of mine, do you have counterexamples?

@Gabriele In my comment above the command pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git#[mysql,postgres]" installs SQLObject but not extrtras, no errors; the last command pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git#egg=sqlobject[mysql,postgres]" works perfectly, it installs SQLObject and extras.

Your command with egg=sqlobject[mysql,postgres] works, but with a deprecation warning referring to PEP 508 (since it's not a bare project name); so I would not say it works perfectly. The one I suggested, instead, does not rise warnings and works with subdirectories as well.

@Gabriele It doesn't install extras, at least for me. The command pip install "git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git#[mysql,postgres]#egg=sqlobject" installs SQLObject but not DB drivers.

Ah I see, I got confused by the absence of errors, sorry! Still, I think that it's not ideal since it's deprecated.
